# How to switch between personal page and Brand Page in the G+ Android app?

Tags: google-plus

In Google Plus, I am able switch between my personal page and Brand Pages. (As described [here](http://www.business2community.com/google-plus/how-to-switch-between-google-plus-personal-and-brand-pages-094407).)

How do I do the same using the Android app version of G+?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process has changed as of version 4.1. You no longer have to sign out and sign back in.

To switch:

- Open the menu by swiping right or tapping the icon in the upper left
- Tap the down arrow next to your name (or your Page's name)
- If necessary, tap "Switch Google+ page"
- Tap the name of the Page you want to switch to

The process is the same to go back to your regular account.

---

This is how to do it with versions 3.2 (or the version updated 11th October depending on your device) to 4.0.x.

To switch:

- Sign out
- Choose your user account (if you have more than one)

  - If you've recently updated the app you may need to go through a few settings screens
- Choose to sign in as yourself or one of your pages

Comment: Not the most intuitive process, but I can imagine that they might have had to do it this way.

Comment: This doesn't work on my phone. I get nothing when I swipe. If I hit the icon, it takes me to the listing of Home, Profile and so on. No arrow next to my name. No option for "Switch Google+ page". Has this changed??

Comment: @DDH  Have you signed in for G+ with both of them? Have you added both accounts in Settings? For me, it's just as in the answer.